# Is there a way to limit app engine to accept request from domain I own / allow only?

Tags: google-app-engine

I found that it's relatively easy to add an app engine app from google apps for business. And seems all you need is the app engine app's ID and you're done, with no authorization needed!

So how do app engine app creator protect their apps from access from other domains?

I know I can do programming to detect which domain the request is from, but what happen to those static files? It seems easy for people to "steal" my work and bandwidth resources by assigning their own domain to it.

Comment: I believe it's possible.  But why would anyone do that?  It really just benefits you by directing more traffic to your site.

Comment: Not sure, say if my site is hosting a lot of image resources, someone else would be easy enough to steal your work by setting up image.example.com and point to my server, then serves images directly from my server while the URL appears as his domain.